# Clear data inside ngOnDestroy but not when shouldReuseRoute is executed

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an Angular component that needs to clear some data when user navigates to some other route. However, I have a shouldReuseRoute strategy implemented for this component and route so as to be able to reuse the already loaded route and component.

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
  if (future.url.toString() === 'route1' && curr.url.toString() === future.url.toString()) {
    return false;
  }
  return (future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig);
};

ngOnDestroy() {
this.data.next(null);
}
```

I want to do this **this.data.next(null);** only when **shouldReuseRoute** strategy is executed that in turn actually calls **ngOnDestroy**. Any suggestions are welcome!

**SOLUTION**

```
this.router.routeReuseStrategy.shouldReuseRoute = (future: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, curr: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) => {
if (future.url.toString() === 'route1' && curr.url.toString() === future.url.toString()) {
    this.routerUsed = true;
    return false;
}
return (future.routeConfig === curr.routeConfig);
  };
  
ngOnDestroy() {
   if (!this.routerUsed) {
    this.data.next(null);
    }
    this.routerUsed = false;
}
```

Comment: I think you could create a callback like `cb = () => {this.data.next(null)}` and include that callback in `shouldReuseRoute`.

Comment: I have updated my code under the label Solution